# load balancing in websphere 8.5

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I have 4 vm machines,
network deployment websphere v 8.5.5

I want to configure vm #4 as load balancer, do you guys know the best way to do this.
I have searched the net but did not find something helpful.

Do you have any idea or links that may help in the load balancer configuration and how to connect it to the admin machine.

What I found that IHS v 8.5.5 may work but I don't know how to configure it.

Comment: Maybe this will be of use? http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/op/v6r2m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.Installation_Guide_WebSphere.6.2.0.doc%2Ft_camphor_copy_the_was_proxy_module_into_ihs.html

Answer (score 0):

Check this page: [Configuring a web server and an application server on separate machines](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tins_webplugins_remotesa.html?lang=en)

You need to:

- Install IHS
- Install WebSphere Plugin
- Configure web server in the web admin console on Deployment manager (I'm assuming that by admin machine you mean machine with Deployment manager).
- For easier management you can configure Remote Web server management described [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cins_webserver.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F3-7-1-6-2&lang=en).

Comment: Gas In the link provided by you above, I think we should copy the configurewe_server_name.bat to the deployment manager bin not the application server bin ?                                           What do you think ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. In case of cell with deployment manager, you run it on deployment manager profile. If you will have any problems with the script, you can always configure web server via admin console instead.